# Split string into string and int

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I am trying to use `sscanf(inputCmd, "%s%d", cmd, value);` to convert the string `inputCmd` into the string `cmd`, and the int `value` in my Arduino sketch. However it isn't working, as apparently the variables are the wrong type (String, instead of char*)

inputCmd is in the format FOO90, and neither the length of the number or the string can be assumed to be constant. What is the best way to separate the 2 parts of `inputCmd` and store them in 2 variables? `cmd` should be FOO, and `value` should be 90.

Thanks.

Comment: Can `FOO` have numbers in it?  like `FOO123BAR42`?

Comment: No, it will only be XXXXXXXYYY, where X are letters and Y are numbers. The length is unknown.

Comment: My understanding is that you have to pass the address of integer variables to `sscanf`, such as `sscanf(inputCmd, "%s%d", cmd, &value);`.

Comment: OK.  Then count until you find the first number and then use that position to split the string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews using &value I get "cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int scanf(const char*, ...)'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the problem with `String` versus `char*`, the `scanf` format `"%s"` reads a *space-delimited* string. If there's no space between the string and the number you can't use `sscanf`.

As a possible solution you can attempt to get a [*substring*](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring) of each part of the input string, and for the number-part [convert it to an `int`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToInt).

To find out the length of the first substring (which should be put into `cmd`) and the starting position of the number, you need to iterate over the characters of the string until you find a [non-alphabetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) character.